# Return id of a non-existing record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array of IDs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To check what records exist in the table I execute this query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The query returns an `id` of every existing record but what if I want to know what records don't exist? For instance if a record with `id: 1` doesn't exist I want this `id` to be returned. How can I do this?

Comment: So basically a...`NOT IN (1, 2, 3,...)`?

Comment: Not really because then I will get all ids from a table that are not equal to (1, 2 ,3...). I want to check only those (In this case six ids) a return these that don't exists. So If 1, 2, 3 are not in a table ,but 4, 5, 6 are in a table... I want to have result with only 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select idlist.id
from (
  select 1 as id
  union all select 2 
  union all select 3 
  union all select 4 
  union all select 5 
  union all select 6 
) as idlist
left join the_table
  on idlist.id = the_table.id
where the_table.id is null;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a5b/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table where id not in(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

The return ids are not exist .